# Azure Table Storage Update making columns as Null

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am using Azure Table Storage Rest Api to Update the entity.
If the entity has 5 columns(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) and I am making a PUT request body something like this.

```
{"col1":"value"}
```

The rest of the columns value is set to NULL.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behavior is because you're performing [`Update Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2) operation which will replaces an entire entity.

If you're only interested in changing just one attribute (property), you need to use [`Merge Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/merge-entity) operation which updates an existing entity by updating the entity's properties. It does not replace the existing entity.

Simply changing your HTTP Request method to `MERGE` from `PUT` should do the trick.

Comment: I do not see the Merge Property in HTTPMETHOD. :(

Comment: Interesting answer because thats not what docs says. Im facing the same issue i'll try merge now .
---
This is what doc say on update : Table Storage doesn't persist null values for properties. Specifying a property with a null value is equivalent to omitting that property in the request.

Comment: Ok but docs also says this : The Update Entity operation replaces the entire entity, and you can use the operation to remove properties.